# Why are so many downvotes without thinking?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, downvote-reason

I might seem new here, but in reality just didn't made it to sign up in the last six years.

But now I did and found that a lot of people downvotes questions and/or answers for no apparent reason.

Are there any system-wide motives doing so?
(Apart from the "vox populi" badge and whatever)

EDIT: More specifically, does anyone gather any system-wide benefits from downvoting others?

Comment: Votes can be arbitrary, but they can also be motivated for the reasoning in the tooltip:  "unclear", "not useful", "no research effort", etc.

Comment: Well, I've already got  four kinda answers.. :P

Comment: FYI: If you want a useful discussion, offending everyone before they even get to open your question (in the title) is *not* the way to go. Not that the body is any better. The only benefit of voting *for the voter* is (hopefully) making the site better by voting according to the posts usefulness. Doing so is too often worth the cost of 1 point on answers (main only, no rep on meta).

Comment: For the full sake of objectivity, I have to state it outright that it was not my personal offence or whatever, I just saw questions I tried to answer moving down without apparent reason.
(And of course, there were those that were downvoted for a profound reason, at least what could come to my mind in an instant.)

Comment: Why are so many questions without thinking?

Comment: I think the intent is for the person being down-voted to gain some benefit, by stepping back and considering how their question and/or answer might be improved.

Comment: The whole world benefits from users downvoting bad questions. If more users did it, the whole world would be a much better place. When a user asks a bad question and it is downvoted to the pits of hell, one of three things may happen. 1) User rage-quits, doesn't ask more bad questions 2) User takes the criticism, learns how to ask better questions, doesn't ask more bad questions 3) User completely disregards downvotes, gets answer, continues to ask bad questions. As you can see, whatever path stops the bad questions is preferred.

Comment: Part of the problem is that there's different levels of programmers.  For a newbie a "below standard question" aka "dumb question" is a real question for them.  But you get a "high end programmer" who thinks it's a below standard question.  Not everyone has the benefit of getting a high end programming education before they start programming.  #NewBeginnerProgrammersLivesMatter

Comment: Isn't this some sort of _elitism_?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only *real* benefit to be gained from downvotes is that the quality filters get a bit more training on what the community does and does not deem as good content on the site.  There's no personal gain for downvotes outside of that, except for perhaps the Vox Populi badge.

Bear in mind, downvotes can happen because people believe the quality of the question to be subpar.  Don't instantly take offense that someone has downvoted content; perhaps it needs to be brought to standards.

Answer (score 5):

The only benefit to a conscientious user for voting is knowing they made the site an infinitisimal bit better.
Knowing that is too often even worth investing the 1 point it costs on answers (main only, no rep on meta).

Votes feed into multiple automatic systems and are a clear indicator for other visitors.
The posts owner is a distinctly secondary target:

- The roomba. Upvoted content cannot be automatically cleaned up.
- VLQ / NAA / delete-vote on answers: Only downvoted answers can be deleted without moderator-intervention.
- Rate-limiting. If the community indicates the user contributes negatively, they are throttled to reduce garbage.
- Moderation priviliges. Reputation (generated by votes ones contributions receive) is a rough measure of the systems trust in the user.
- ...

Comment: And is it similarly justifiable to downvote answers for the apparently sole reason of being posted to questions that lately turned out to be "vlq"?

Comment: You downvote for not being useful. Is an answer to a low-quality question useful? Unlikely, but not impossible. One wonders why the answerer didn't find the question worth fixing but found it worth answering...

Comment: Is it that I can edit questions at will if I think I understand it and can represent the essence more? (Sorry for being a noob)

Comment: [You are encouraged to polish/fix any post you come over](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) (though on meta that requires full editing priviliges). Though try to make every edit count, so fix as much as possible in one go, and don't neglect the summary, at least if you change much / it isn't blindingly obvious that your edit is good (justify and give motivation, don't just restate). Approved suggested edits even give you a tiny amount of rep.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.